# Multiple collection view in table view scrolling at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have collection view as rows of a tableview. The collection view only supports horizontal scrolling. When I scroll to the end of the collection view in the first row, and then scroll to the bottom of the tableview. The last collection view is also at the end position when I haven't even touched that yet.

I know that the issue is because of `dequeueReusableCell` of the tableview. I have tried using the `prepareForReuse()` in `UITableViewCell`.

I expect that whenever any other row of the table view should remain unaffected by the interaction done on rest of the table view rows.

Comment: for doing this you need to store last visible indexpath of collection view in model and when ever willDisplayCell called you need to animate collection view to that position

Comment: I can identify the last visible cell using `collectionView.visibleCells.first`. But how to get the indexpath for this

Comment: You need to show your code, otherwise we’re just guessing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could store (and restore) the collection views' content offsets by using the table view's delegate methods:

```
var xOffsets: [IndexPath: CGFloat] = [:]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    xOffsets[indexPath] = (cell as? TableViewCell)?.collectionView.contentOffset.x
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    (cell as? TableViewCell)?.collectionView.contentOffset.x = xOffsets[indexPath] ?? 0
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much.